# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod “5.0.0-beta.1"

Tags: ios, alamofire, swift4.2

I want to use ‘Alamofire’, ‘~> 5.0.0-beta.1’via CocoaPods in my swift project.

I am getting the following error when after pod install in command line.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Alamofire":
In Podfile:
Alamofire (= 5.0.0-beta.1)

AlamofireObjectMapper (= 6.0.0) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
  Alamofire (~> 5.0.0-beta.2)
```

Please help.

Comment: What happens if you ask for 5.0.0-beta.2 in the podfile

Comment: [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Alamofire":
In Podfile:
Alamofire (= 5.0.0-beta.2)

Answer (score 0):

You can tried this the current stable version.

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.2'
```

But this version need **Swift 5.1+**

So you can use this version for **Swift 4.2**

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7.3'
```

Comment: I have to use 5.0.0-beta.1 only.

Comment: Use `5.0.0` instead of `5.0.0-beta.1`. This beta version is not available. Or you can use the latest stable version `5.2`.